# How to create a translucid/alpha-transparent rectangle using wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, transparency, transparent, translucency

I have a wx.panel and I want to put a translucid rectangle on a part of it.

How can I do that using wxpython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [wx.GraphicsContext](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GraphicsContext-class.html), and there's a good example in the wxPython demo (located in the Miscellaneous category).